# Xcode 10 'frame' is only available on iOS 12.0 or newer compilation error iOS 12 beta

Tags: ios, xcode10, ios12

I am trying to compile my project in Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w) (10L176w) ... I am getting the error  **'frame' is only available on iOS 12.0 or newer**

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func btnAddToCartAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let btnCart:UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    let boundsCenter:CGPoint = btnCart.bounds.offsetBy(dx: sender.frame.size.width/2, dy: btnCart.frame.size.height/2).origin;

}
```

Which compiles fine in Xcode 9

Comment: Xcode 10 uses the new build system. Try changing it to Legacy Build System by going to `File -> Project/Workspace Settings -> Build System -> Legacy/Standard Build System`.

Comment: I have updated my code and also got the answer ... basically AnyObject.frame was some how compiling properly in Xcode 9 not in Xcode 10 anymore

Comment: @BadhanGanesh: This didn't mute the error, any help?! Mihir's answer won't help because it's a huge project and I can't apply his fix everywhere.

Comment: You have to apply fix i think. Because Apple will soon stop accepting build from Xcode 9. So you have to use XCode10 (Infact Xcode 10.1) and apply fix in case Legacy build system doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 7):

Basically in Xcode 9 `AnyObject.frame` was compiling successfully , but in XCode10 it stops compiling which make sense...

You need to convert it into `UIButton` or `UIView` before accessing it's frame property ...

So final code would be

```
@IBAction func didTapOnCheckMarkButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let btnCart:UIButton = sender as! UIButton
        let boundsCenter:CGPoint = btnCart.bounds.offsetBy(dx: btnCart.frame.size.width/2, dy: btnCart.frame.size.height/2).origin;
         ...

}
```

Comment: It's better to change the parameter of the method to `UIButton` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Click on error (hint) and choose solution (`Fix`) of your query. (It will suggest you possible solution)

[image]

Or

Replace `AnyObject` with `UIButton` in function parameter argument type.

```
@IBAction func btnAddToCartAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //let btnCart:UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    let boundsCenter:CGPoint = sender.bounds.offsetBy(dx: sender.frame.size.width/2, dy: sender.frame.size.height/2).origin;

}
```

Or

Use `btnCart` instance, inplace of `sender`

```
@IBAction func btnAddToCartAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let btnCart:UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    let boundsCenter:CGPoint = btnCart.bounds.offsetBy(dx: btnCart.frame.size.width/2, dy: btnCart.frame.size.height/2).origin;

}
```